# How to detect if product has a price Rule in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom extension in Magento 1 to check if a product has a price rule and then apply some customs rules, im using this in Observer: sales_quote_collect_totals_before, this means that the rule should apply when Magento needs to update totals when people add something to cart or checkout.

My problem is that Magento doesnt fire my Observer, this is my config.xml the extensions is being loaded because i can see it on Dashboard.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_Module>
  </modules>
  <global>
        <models>
            <coupons>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
            </coupons>
        </models>
        <events>
    <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        <observers>
            <namespace_module>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>setLog</method>
            </namespace_module>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
</events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Then in Model folder i got my Observer.php with

```
<?php 
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer

{

 public function setLog(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        Mage::log("Info: ", null, "test.log", true);
    }
 }
```

So the problem is, not log is being created when the user add a product to cart, whats wrong?

Comment: Silly question, but sometimes people forget stuff... Are you sure the Observer does not fire? Have you enables the error log from the configuration?

Comment: Hi there, yes, because the log file is not being created, it should add test.log file at var/log , yes errors ar enabled. Config file its ok?

Comment: config seems OK, although I would suggest adding the observer under frontend instead of global... Also, be sure to refresh or disable caching and to disable compilation or disable it.

Comment: I would suggest to create a breakpoint in the observer using Xdebug, you cannot trust in Mage::log 100% if the logs records are not working properly